# What difference will the more skillful (1 star or 2 star) crew members make compared to a non-skilled one in FTL?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I checked out all tooltips in the game and their official website. Since FTL did not come with a manual I have no clue here. I know that they have something to do with recharge rates and percentages but I can't find anything specific about it.

Comment: Are you asking for specific percentages, or just what areas they improve?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Float your mouse over a crew member's name, then over the skill they've trained.  That will show the current benefits they're providing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It varies from system to system as follows ("manned" or 0 level/1 level/2 level)

1. Engines - increases evasion 5%/7%/10%.
2. Shields - increases recharge rate 10%/20%/29%
3. Weapons - reduced charge time 10%/15%/19%
4. Piloting - increase evasion 5%/7%/10%.  Also, with no pilot and no auto-pilot you get 0% evasion regardless of the level/power of engines!
5. Melee - increases combat damage, 0/10%/20%
6. Repair - increases repair speed 0/10%?/20%?? (seems likely)

[Source here](http://ftlwiki.com/wiki/Crew#Skills), and also from help in the comments.

Comment: Also, repair - decrease time 0%/10%/? (never got anyone up that high).

Comment: @Allen - do you know if it's 10% at level 1?  I've never seen hard numbers.  Forgot to mention repair, will add.

Comment: That's my recollection, but I'm at work right now and can't look to confirm. Will update.

Comment: Update: one-star melee is +10% damage according to the tooltip.

Comment: @Allen nice, added.

Comment: Can confirm that two-star melee is +20% damage (been abusing my teleporter privileges).

Comment: This is beautiful.  Outstanding work, both of you!