# Who is the best fighter?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Think in a room where we teleport two member enemies between them, at the same time. Which race will win?

Mantis has more damage, but Rockmen have more life. Lanius will remove the oxygen of the room before they die in a fight, suffocating enemies, but Crystal members have suffocation resistance.

Zoltan, Engi, Slug and humans will always lose, I think. But between each pair of the rest what would be the result? Maybe when skills are maxed there is different results?

So which is the best race to fight against what?

Comment: the answer is always, it depends.  In a fire?  rockmen are best hands down.  In a vacuum?  Lanius.  In an enemy medbay?  Mantis.

Comment: @z- In a empty room without external conditions

Comment: I've not tested it, but assuming that with the Mantis having a higher attack, and the Rockman having higher health, and that these "perks" balance each other out - then it would all depend on who got the first "hit" in.

Comment: The lanius would lose against the mantis because the oxygen deprivation wouldn't start being a problem for the mantis until well after the lanius is already bleeding badly and likely to die.

Comment: @Shadur Two lanius is another matter.  The only things I would consider a real threat to two Lanius in a small room are Mantis or Zoltan (for the death explosion) - and those are both even matches.

Comment: @Brilliand the Crystal guys vs. Lanius would be a good test also, since they have 125 health and reduced suffocation damage.

Comment: @spudone That would play out very similar to Rock vs. Lanius.  With the Rock, the suffocation needs to deal 50 damage to make the fight even; with the Crystal, the suffocation needs to deal 25 damage at half damage, which takes the same amount of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just comparing the Mantis and Rockman in a completely neutral scenario:

Lets assume X is the damage an average race deals (such as Human or Zoltan).

A fully trained Mantis has a bonus of 1.7 damage with a health of 100.

A fully trained Rockman has a bonus of 1.2 damage with a health of 150

A mantis would take 150/1.7X to kill a Rockman, while a Rockman would take 100/1.2X to kill a mantis.

You'll see that the amount of time it takes a mantis to kill a Rockman is greater than the amount of time it takes a Rockman to kill a mantis for all Values of X*.  Outside of damage variations, the Rockman will always win.  Therefore, in a controlled environment the fully trained Rockman is the best hand to hand fighter.

*Once the values become large, the difference can come down to who gets in the first hit.

*update*

According to the research in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/168761/3917), a single lanius won't be able to drain the room fast enough to affect the combat outcome (assuming level 1 oxygen).

Comment: This presumes the level 2 melee bonus is additive and not multiplicative - is this the case? Have never checked, and this [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/87521/49798) doesn't say.

Comment: @Affine if its multiplicative, at best the mantis would tie the rockman.  All in all I still prefer rockmen for boarding due to great synergy with fire bombs.

Comment: The Mantis have more tactical options than rockmen. You can kite them much easier while waiting for recharge, you can chase runners, you can win in a working medbay against enemies with greater health. Rockmen have fire synergy, but that's RNG-dependent for the most part