# How long does it take for a Lanius to drain a room of oxygen?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In an attempt to answer [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168556/who-is-the-best-fighter) I need to figure whether or oxygen deprivation damage is a factor in a straight up fight.  So my question is, in the following scenarios, how long does it take a room to achieve the 'deprivation' state where non Lanius crew take damage?

- 1 Lanius with level 1, 2, 3 oxygen
- 2 Lanius with level 1, 2, 3 oxygen

Does room size matter in terms of oxygen draining speed?

Comment: Oxygen deprivation is definitely a factor - my two-Lanius boarding party seems to be about evenly matched with a pair of Mantis.  A lone Lanius might not be able to drain oxygen fast enough to matter, though.

Comment: room size does not matter, not for the overall % of your ship's total oxygen level (another achievement with the lanius cruiser) and not for the draining.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've done some experiments for this purpose...

- I moved a Lanius into a full-oxygen room with a human, at at the same moment, moved an Engi into the no-oxygen room the Lanius had just occupied.  When the human started taking damage, I paused and checked the results.

  - With level 1 oxygen, the Engi had 8 health then I paused, and the human had 97
  - With oxygen unpowered, the engi had 31 health when I paused, and the human had 97

With level 3 oxygen, the lanius was not able to drain the room, although he could at level 2 oxygen.  2 Lanius was enough to drain a room at level 3 oxygen, and oddly enough, at level 3 oxygen, *2 lanius in connected rooms could drain both rooms when the door was open, but couldn't drain either room when the door was shut.* Air draining from rooms doesn't follow the simple formula of "air is drained from each room individually, and air filters between rooms through doorways"; open doorways seem to actually enhance a Lanius's air-draining abilities.

To establish a baseline, here's how much damage the oxygen-loving crew were able to take before an empty room refilled with oxygen at each level of oxygen power:

- level 1 oxygen: 27
- level 2 oxygen: 7
- level 3 oxygen: 4

After a bit more testing, here are my estimates:

- Base oxygen loss is 1% per second
- Level 1 oxygen provides 2% oxygen per second
- Each Lanius in a room drains 10% oxygen per second
- Each Lanius in an adjacent room with an open door drains 7% oxygen per second

  - I believe this continues exponentially (the effect reducing by roughly 30% per door).  Two Lanius 4 doors apart can drain each other's rooms (and the intervening hallway) at level 3 oxygen, but two Lanius 5 doors apart cannot.
- Oxygen-loving crew begin taking damage at 5% oxygen, at a rate equal to an untrained human's damage output, and to a level 1 Medbay's healing rate (approximately 20 HP every 3 seconds)

In battle, this amounts to:

- 1 Lanius at 0 oxygen power: 9 seconds of 100% damage, then 200% damage thereafter
- 2 Lanius at 0 oxygen power: 5 seconds of 100% damage, then 200% damage thereafter
- 1 Lanius at 1 oxygen power: 11 seconds of 100% damage, then 200% damage thereafter
- 2 Lanius at 1 oxygen power: 5 seconds of 100% damage, then 200% damage thereafter
- 1 Lanius at 2 oxygen power: 19 seconds of 100% damage, then 200% damage thereafter
- 2 Lanius at 2 oxygen power: 6 seconds of 100% damage, then 200% damage thereafter
- 1 Lanius at 3 oxygen power: Oxygen never drains
- 2 Lanius at 3 oxygen power: 11 seconds of 100% damage, then 200% damage thereafter

What this means to beat various races in equal-numbered combat (1 vs 1, 2 vs 2):

- Mantis: The oxygen must drain in under 5 seconds (takes 3 Lanius for a win)

  - 2 Lanius get a fair fight at oxygen 1 or less; if the Lanius escape at very low health, the Mantis will likely die of suffocation afterward.
- Rock or Crystal: The oxygen must drain in under 7.5 seconds (takes 2 Lanius, oxygen 2 or less)
- Human, slug: The oxygen must drain in under 15 seconds for an advantage (takes 2 Lanius if oxygen is at 2 or more)
- Engi, single Zoltan: The Lanius will win regardless.
- 2 Zoltan: The oxygen must drain in under 10.5 seconds to ensure survival (takes 2 Lanius if oxygen is powered, takes 3 Lanius if oxygen is at level 3).
- 3 or more Zoltan: Everyone dies.

Comment: I think you have a mistake. When you say "Engi had 8 health" maybe you mean 80? It makes no sense to me that with oxygen unpowered the Engi had more health that when powered.

Comment: @SysDragon The Engi was standing in a no-oxygen room (with another Lanius in it) while it waited for the human to take damage.  The longer the human stayed safe, the more hurt the Engi got.

Comment: props to you for doing all that testing.

Answer (score 2):

As [wiki](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Races/Lanius) says:

> They drain Oxygen about as fast as a hull breach in a single square.

The exact time depends on the oxygen in the room.

Comment: Don't hull breaches drain at different speeds depending on how bad they are?  IMO, this falls far short of answering the question.

Comment: Actually, hull breaches don't appear to change how fast they drain air based on how serious they are - even a tiny crack is enough to prevent a room from becoming safe with level 1 oxygen.